# Punctuality of the Ferry from Dubrovnik to Rijeka

Tags: ferries, croatia, dubrovnik

I am planning a trip to Croatia this summer. On our last leg, we are planning to be in Dubrovnik. Our flight back home leaves on the 22nd at 10am from Rijeka on the other side of Croatia. I saw there is a ferry by *jadrolinija* that leaves Dubrovnik in the evening and arrives at 7am in Rijeka.

That gives uses 3 hours to spare between the flight departure and the ferry arrival. Considering it takes a cab 30mns to go from the ferry terminal to the airport, it gives us 2 hours and 30 minutes to spare - in other words, the ferry could be 1 hour late and we would still be fine.

Does anyone know how punctual the services are?

Answer (score 1):

Ferries in Europe are generally pretty reliable, however you aren't giving yourself much room for error.

If you can take the ferry a day earlier, you would save yourself a lot of stress by not having to worry about making such a narrow window. But they usually depart/arrive on time, so you probably wouldn't have an issue.

I found a forum about Croatian ferries at: http://www.croatiaferries.com/forum/index.php you might get a better (or more specific) response there.